# Executing Transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk

Looking at the above, I can approve a transaction taking the txHash from the API.
But if I want to execute the transaction as below it takes a safeTransaction

```js
const ethAdapterOwner3 = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signer: owner3 })
const safeSdk3 = await safeSdk2.connect({ ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner3, safeAddress })
const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk3.executeTransaction(safeTransaction)
await executeTxResponse.wait()
```

How do I load back the safeTransaction? My usecase is that when a transaction is created, owners will be notified and they'll be informed to login to the app to sign the transactions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters of a Safe transaction are available via the Safe transaction service. The Safe core sdk provides a [Safe Service Client package](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-service-client) for easy interaction with the api.

There you can use the [`safeService.getTransaction(safeTxHash)`](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-service-client#gettransaction) to retrieve the information.

Full example would be along the lines of:

```js
import SafeServiceClient from '@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client'

// Mainnet service url
const safeService = new SafeServiceClient('https://safe-transaction.mainnet.gnosis.io')
const apiTx: SafeMultisigTransactionResponse = await safeService.getTransaction(safeTxHash)
const safeTx = await safeSdk3.createTransaction({
  ...apiTx,
  data: apiTx.data || "0x",
  gasPrice: parseInt(apiTx.gasPrice)
})
// Sign transaction as owner 3
await safeSdk3.signTransaction(safeTx)
const { hash } = await safeSdk3.executeTransaction(safeTx)
```

Currently it is not easily possible to use the confirmations from the service with the core sdk.

You can map the confirmations returned from the api with the following code:

```js
import { EthSignSignature } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'
apiTx.confirmations?.forEach((confirmation) => {
  safeTx.addSignature(new EthSignSignature(confirmation.owner, confirmation.signature))
})
```

I created the following issues to improve this flow:

- https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/125
- https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/126