# How to use Safe Core SDK & Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API together?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

What I understood is using [Safe Core SDK](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk) - we can create safes and execute transactions and using [Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API](https://safe-transaction.polygon.gnosis.io/) we can track the transactions. If this is correct then:

- How to get access to Gnosis Safe Transaction Service API as I can see some authorization is needed?
- How to coordinate between these two like -  if SDK can be used on the frontend and API can be used on the backend then how the flow should look like to create, sign, execute and track a transaction?

My use case is to let the users deploy safes on polygon blockchain and then use it for storing assets.

Comment: You can get quite some info for this on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116909/executing-transaction

Comment: Thanks, [Richard](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/60740/richard). So, basically, I can use [Safe Service Client SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-service-client) as it consumes Safe Transaction Service API. Also, I can follow this [guide](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/HEAD/packages/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md) to understand the coordination between these 2 SDKs, right?

Comment: Yes that should be correct, except for the 2 points mentioned in the other question (for which issues have been opened on the github repo)