# Creating a Txn end to end

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Hi not needing this now but I think the docs needs some work to produce a start to end flow of all the code as the parts and pieces don't really work together currently.

1. I start with the below from safe-core-sdk

import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk-types'

const transaction: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
to: '0x',
value: '<eth_value_in_wei>',
data: '0x'
}
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction)
I can sign the txns and all fined.

2. I follow your code as below but it returns 404 as below.
   [Executing Transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116909/executing-transaction)

const apiTx: SafeMultisigTransactionResponse = await safeService.getTransaction('')

On https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/, I can see 2 txns with safe address
0x5dAFC062A69F3646397CdF1a175E90666b8AEFF3 using the /safes/{address}/all-transactions/ but these don't appear with /safes/{address}/multisig-transactions/.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation/ guide for this on the [safe-core-sdk repo](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md#5-propose-the-transaction-to-the-service)

Also the all-transactions endpoint only returns transactions with that have a confirmation from an owner, to avoid malicious spamming of transactions.

On the swagger of the [transaction service](https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/) it says:

```
Multisig Transactions for a Safe. tx_type=MULTISIG_TRANSACTION. If the query parameter queued=False is
set only the transactions with safe nonce < current Safe nonce will be displayed. By default, only the
trusted transactions will be displayed (transactions indexed, with at least one confirmation or proposed
by a delegate). If you need that behaviour to be disabled set the query parameter trusted=False
```

The same applies to the official Safe interface, it will always only return transactions that have at least one confirmation from an owner or a delegate of an owner.