# ​POST /safes​/{address}​/multisig-transactions​/ not working (Rinkeby)

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to propose a transaction via [https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/{address}​/multisig-transactions​/](https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/%7Baddress%7D%E2%80%8B/multisig-transactions%E2%80%8B/)

I'm getting 201's responses from the API but no transactions are showing up in the Safe UI queue.

Any help or tips? Have I missed something completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Safe UI only shows transactions that have been confirmed by an owner or delegate.

This is also mentioned in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117138/creating-a-txn-end-to-end).