# Proposed transaction doesnt appear in queue, and can't be confirmed

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I'm using the safe-core-sdk to propose a transaction to my Gnosis safe.

Once proposed, I can view the transaction by going to it directly with this URL: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0xA0385041eB8ec23aD04a76C8A50b85ca0C7Ff770/transactions/0x2caa1060ab60823b92782baba7acfe7f832369742d88e2ccd23a1618d78e4651

However it doesn't appear in the queue.

The more serious problem is that once I do go to that direct link, if I click confirm the confirm button flashes twice, but doesnt do anything. I'm connected with a metamask wallet, and would expect a dialogue to pop-up to sign the confirmation.

If I propose transactions via the UI, rather than the SDK, I can confirm and execute them as usual. I've also been able to propose transactions with previous versions of the core-safe-sdk.

Comment: Regarding this: "I've also been able to propose transactions with previous versions of the core-safe-sdk", can you share the code you are using (including creation of the transaction and proposing it to the service? What version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [​POST /safes​/{address}​/multisig-transactions​/ not working (Rinkeby)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117185/post-safes-address-multisig-transactions-not-working-rinkeby)

Comment: @Germán I'm using safe-service-client 1.1.1. There used to be an option to send a signature to `proposeTransaction` but now there doesn't seem to be? How should I do this?

Comment: @BarefootDev make sure the `safeTransaction` param includes the signature. Now it is passed inside this object instead of passing it as a different param. Initialize the `safe-core-sdk` with the sender address and call this method (https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts#L354) before proposing it in order to sign the transaction

Comment: Thanks it's sorted now. Ill post as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer points out, the transaction will only appear in the Queue if has at least 1 signature.

To provide that signature with the latest version of Gnosis `core-safe-sdk` (1.1.1) I run the following:

```
const safeTransaction: SafeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(
    safeTransactionData
  );

const txHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);

const signature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(txHash);

safeTransaction.addSignature(signature);

await safeService.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress: gnosisSafeAddress,
    senderAddress: signer.address,
    safeTransaction: safeTransaction,
    safeTxHash: txHash
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The interface only shows transactions with at least one owner signature. Otherwise, it would be possible to spam/propose malicious transactions by anyone. Your transaction has 0 signatures.